# Checking if array is multidimensional or not?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, element

1. What is the most efficient way to check if an array is **a flat array
   of primitive values** or if it is a **multidimensional array**?
2. Is there any way to do this without actually looping through an
   array and running `is_array()` on each of its elements?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that PHP does not have true multi-dimensional arrays -- just simple associative array's of values.  So your question is really asking "is there a non-scalar value in my array"?

Comment: Actually... I don't think that's worth pointing out at all.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The short answer is no you can't do it without at least looping implicitly if the 'second dimension' could be anywhere. If it has to be in the first item, you'd just do

```
is_array($arr[0]);
```

But, the most efficient general way I could find is to use a foreach loop on the array, shortcircuiting whenever a hit is found (at least the implicit loop is better than the straight for()):

```
$ more multi.php
<?php

$a = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b',3 => array(1,2,3));
$b = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b');
$c = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b','foo' => array(1,array(2)));

function is_multi($a) {
    $rv = array_filter($a,'is_array');
    if(count($rv)>0) return true;
    return false;
}

function is_multi2($a) {
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function is_multi3($a) {
    $c = count($a);
    for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {
        if (is_array($a[$i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
$iters = 500000;
$time = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $iters; $i++) {
    is_multi($a);
    is_multi($b);
    is_multi($c);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo "is_multi  took ".($end-$time)." seconds in $iters times\n";

$time = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $iters; $i++) {
    is_multi2($a);
    is_multi2($b);
    is_multi2($c);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo "is_multi2 took ".($end-$time)." seconds in $iters times\n";
$time = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $iters; $i++) {
    is_multi3($a);
    is_multi3($b);
    is_multi3($c);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo "is_multi3 took ".($end-$time)." seconds in $iters times\n";
?>

$ php multi.php
is_multi  took 7.53565130424 seconds in 500000 times
is_multi2 took 4.56964588165 seconds in 500000 times
is_multi3 took 9.01706600189 seconds in 500000 times
```

Implicit looping, but we can't shortcircuit as soon as a match is found...

```
$ more multi.php
<?php

$a = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b',3 => array(1,2,3));
$b = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b');

function is_multi($a) {
    $rv = array_filter($a,'is_array');
    if(count($rv)>0) return true;
    return false;
}

var_dump(is_multi($a));
var_dump(is_multi($b));
?>

$ php multi.php
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: Good, with the caveat that I believe that your filtering line should have array_map("is_array",$a), not using is_array as a bareword.

Comment: Good catch, that sped up is_multi, but still not good enough to match foreach

Comment: It is worth noting that, as written, multi_3 will only work on zero-based non-associative arrays with no gaps in the indices, meaning it won't correctly identify any of these examples as multi-dimensional.

Comment: In function `is_multi()` optimize the code by doing `return count($rv)>0`

Comment: is_array(array_values($arr)[0]) as a workaround for customized keys.

Answer (score 233):

Use count() twice; one time in default mode and one time in recursive mode. If the values match, the array is *not* multidimensional, as a multidimensional array would have a higher recursive count.

```
if (count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) 
{
  echo 'array is not multidimensional';
}
else
{
  echo 'array is multidimensional';
}
```

This option second value `mode` was added in PHP 4.2.0. From the [PHP Docs](http://us.php.net/count):

> If the optional mode parameter is set to COUNT_RECURSIVE (or 1), count() will recursively count the array. This is particularly useful for counting all the elements of a multidimensional array. count() does not detect infinite recursion.

However this method does not detect `array(array())`.

Comment: As noted this does not work for elements with empty arrays

Comment: This answer is provably incorrect and the post score indicates that MANY researchers have been misled. https://3v4l.org/ptGQ9

Answer (score 29):

For PHP 4.2.0 or newer:

```
function is_multi($array) {
    return (count($array) != count($array, 1));
}
```

Comment: Not working for `array(array())` or `array(array(), array())` either. Generally, if an inside array is empty then the recursive count will correctly add 0 for it, thus making it match the normal count.

Comment: This answer is provably unreliable. https://3v4l.org/LLg2t

Answer (score 12):

I think this is the most straight forward way and it's state-of-the-art:

```
function is_multidimensional(array $array) {
    return count($array) !== count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
}
```

Comment: This unreliable technique was already recommended by multiple answers on this page years earlier.  This answer adds no new value to the page.

Answer (score 10):

After PHP 7 you could simply do:

```
public function is_multi(array $array):bool
{
    return is_array($array[array_key_first($array)]);
}
```

Comment: You just check the first array element if it is an array. What if it is not but the 2nd element is an array? For example `$array = ['0' => 0, '1' => ['0' => 1]];` This is a multidim array but your function says false.

Answer (score 7):

You could look check `is_array()` on the first element, under the assumption that if the first element of an array is an array, then the rest of them are too.

Comment: That's actually a good point. In my particular case, it's an either/or situation since I am controlling the creation of the original array. I'll leave the question open for now in case there's a solution that might work more generally though.

Comment: Like this: `if( is_array(current($arr)) ) { // is multidimensional }`

Comment: This is only a valid option if the first level of the array has consistent data types.

Answer (score 4):

I think you will find that this function is the simplest, most efficient, and fastest way.

```
function isMultiArray($a){
    foreach($a as $v) if(is_array($v)) return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

You can test it like this:

```
$a = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b',3 => array(1,2,3));
$b = array(1 => 'a',2 => 'b');

echo isMultiArray($a) ? 'is multi':'is not multi';
echo '<br />';
echo isMultiArray($b) ? 'is multi':'is not multi';
```

Comment: if you're going to one-line it at least do the whole thing; `foreach($a as $v) is_array($v) ? return TRUE : return FALSE;`

Comment: @RobertPounder or even `foreach($a as $v) return is_array($v) ? true : false;`

Comment: Uuuuuuumm, no, RobertPounder and YassineSedrani.  You can't one-liner it like that; that would create different logic.  Returning on the first iteration does not check the whole array.  You might as well just evaluate on the first element if you are going to unconditionally return early.  No.  For a fully reliable solution, you need to allow the possibility of iterating the full array as a pathway to determining the opposite data type.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use COUNT_RECURSIVE

[click this site for know why](https://pageconfig.com/post/checking-multidimensional-arrays-in-php)

use rsort and then use isset

```
function is_multi_array( $arr ) {
rsort( $arr );
return isset( $arr[0] ) && is_array( $arr[0] );
}
//Usage
var_dump( is_multi_array( $some_array ) );
```

Comment: $arr[0] could not be and array but  $arr[1] could be an array

Comment: This answer has a larger time complexity than is necessary because sorting is more expensive than merely iterating every element in the array.  I would not recommend this answer for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

Even this works

```
is_array(current($array));
```

If **false** its a **single dimension** array if **true** its a **multi dimension** array.

**current** will give you the first element of your array and check if the first element is an array or not by **is_array** function.

Comment: That won't be reliable if you want to ensure that any other element isn't nested either.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return int number of array dimensions (stolen from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191229075210/http://www.theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.array.php#49219)).

```
function countdim($array)
{
   if (is_array(reset($array))) 
     $return = countdim(reset($array)) + 1;
   else
     $return = 1;
 
   return $return;
}
```

Comment: This will only work for Greg's case. It's not a general solution to the problem where the second dimension could be anywhere in the array

Comment: $arr = array("hello", "hi" => "hi there");

$arr[] = &arr; //oops

Comment: This answer does not check multiple elements in each level.  This answer is very untrustworthy for this asked question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a simple check like this:

```
$array = array('yo'=>'dream', 'mydear'=> array('anotherYo'=>'dream'));
$array1 = array('yo'=>'dream', 'mydear'=> 'not_array');

function is_multi_dimensional($array){
    $flag = 0;
    while(list($k,$value)=each($array)){
        if(is_array($value))
            $flag = 1;
    }
    return $flag;
}
echo is_multi_dimensional($array); // returns 1
echo is_multi_dimensional($array1); // returns 0
```

Comment: This answer is not optimized because it does not conditionally return early.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is classy (props to another user I don't know his username):

```
static public function isMulti($array)
{
    $result = array_unique(array_map("gettype",$array));

    return count($result) == 1 && array_shift($result) == "array";
}
```

Comment: This is not going to be a performant solution -- `array_map()` does not allow short circuiting, so the FULL array will be iterated.  There are other solutions on this page that are better than this one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I stuck in vary strange condition.
1st case = `array("data"=> "name");`
2nd case = `array("data"=> array("name"=>"username","fname"=>"fname"));`
But if `data` has array instead of value then sizeof() or count() function not work for this condition. Then i create custom function to check.

If first index of array have value then it return "only value" 
But if index have array instead of value then it return "has array" 
I use this way

```
 function is_multi($a) {
        foreach ($a as $v) {
          if (is_array($v)) 
          {
            return "has array";
            break;
          }
          break;
        }
        return 'only value';
    }
```

Special thanks to [Vinko Vrsalovic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145337/checking-if-array-is-multidimensional-or-not/145348#145348)

Comment: This code is not reliable; it only checks the first element.  Why `break` inside of the condition if you are going to `break` immediately after the condition?  Why use any `break`s if you are only going to `return` after `break`ing?  This is just another verbose version of other earlier answers on this page that do not do a great job of evaluating the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as

```
$isMulti = !empty(array_filter($array, function($e) {
                    return is_array($e);
                }));
```

Comment: This is not going to be a performant solution -- `array_filter()` does not allow short circuiting, so the FULL array will be iterated.  There are other solutions on this page that are better than this one.  It is needless to call the `empty()` function when the passed in value is guaranteed to exist.  `!empty()` can be replaced with a function-less type cast `(bool)`.

Answer (score -1):

Try as follows

```
if (count($arrayList) != count($arrayList, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) 
{
  echo 'arrayList is multidimensional';

}else{

  echo 'arrayList is no multidimensional';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$is_multi_array = array_reduce(array_keys($arr), function ($carry, $key) use ($arr) { return $carry && is_array($arr[$key]); }, true);
```

Here is a nice one liner. It iterates over every key to check if the value at that key is an array. This will ensure true

Comment: This is not going to be a performant solution -- `array_reduce()` does not allow short circuiting, so the FULL array will be iterated.  There are other solutions on this page that are better than this one.