# Check if an array is multi-dimensional

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if array is multidimensional or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145337/checking-if-array-is-multidimensional-or-not)

How do I check whether an array is multidimensional or not in PHP?

Comment: I think this one has a better "answer", assuming OM's gets picked

Comment: @Ascherer: That answer is also available in the duplicated question. I'd be much more in favor of editing that answer with additional information than keeping a duplicate question open.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use count twice, one with single parameter, and one with recursive mode

```
if (count($myarray) == count($myarray, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) 
{
  echo 'MyArray is not multidimensional';
}
else
{
  echo 'MyArray is multidimensional';
}
```

> count(array,mode)

- array ---Required. Specifies the array or object to count.
- mode ---Optional. Specifies the mode of the function. Possible values:

  - 0 - Default. Does not detect multidimensional arrays (arrays within arrays)
  - 1 - Detects multidimensional arrays

> **Note: This parameter was added in PHP 4.2**

Comment: This wont work if array like this - ['a','b',[]]

Comment: Code is working perfectly. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 3):

Multi-dimensional arrays in PHP are simply arrays containing arrays. So a simple function for this could be written as

```
function is_multidim_array($arr) {
  if (!is_array($arr))
    return false;
  foreach ($arr as $elm) {
    if (!is_array($elm))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This will run through every element of `$arr` and check whether it's an array. Should it encounter an element that is not an array, it will return false. Otherwise, return true.

Comment: Depends on what you consider multidimensional. I would consider any array that contains another array to be multidimensional. Every single value doesn't necessarily *have* be another array.

Comment: I would consider any array whose direct children were also arrays to be multidimensional

Comment: This doesn't work for `[1, [1, 2]]`.

Comment: @Antti29 That depends on the definition of multidimensional. The description in my (almost 5 years old) answer also makes the definition I've used clear – every child has to be an array. Whether that's the right definition for the task at hand, I can't say. :-)

Comment: @kba `arrays containing arrays`, my example meets this criterion, no? I'd rather switch the second `if` around and return `false` in the end.

Comment: As I said, it depends on your definition. If that's what your definition is, then yes, your suggestion would work.