# checking if a value is a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How come when I run this code, I get an output of `I am a multidimensional array!` (the first block). I thought it would go into the second block, but it doesn't. What am I missing here?

```
$values = array('1','2');
if(isset($values[0][0])){
    echo "I am a multidimensional array!";
}else{
    echo "I am not a multidimensional array.";
}
```

Comment: If i run that i don't get same as you...

Comment: Works just [fine for me](http://codepad.org/gtcfK0iC).

Comment: Check [this nice trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/994599/1401975). By the way your question is a duplicate ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$values = array(1,array(1,2));


$multi = false;
if(is_array($values)){
    foreach($values as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $multi = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $multi ? "multi" : "not multi";
```

Comment: This solution is better since it will support more than integer keys.

Comment: Thanks, I had to modify it to work with my code, because I needed all values in the array to be arrays not just some. But this solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(is_array($values[0]))
```

**Edit: This will check the first element of the array only. You should loop through each element to check if its truly multidimensional.**

This code checks to see if the first element of the array is also an array. `isset` just checks whether or not a variable is `NULL`.

`isset` in your example is not working as expected. Perhaps there is a slight difference in functionality between PHP versions or setups. I didn't see anything in the manual but maybe you can:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Using `is_array` is more semantic, so in my opinion is a much better choice.

Comment: Oh, but the code worked for me [here](http://codepad.org/gtcfK0iC).

Comment: that is odd, but this answer fixed my issue.

Comment: Perhaps `isset` has slightly different functionality between PHP versions. I brushed through the manual but nothing stood out.

Comment: `$values = array(1,array(1,2));` this doesn't work

Comment: *rolls eyes* his example only checked the first element as well. I'll update it with a note.

Answer (score 1):

This code only goes into the if-branch for me, if the first value in the array is explicitly declared as a string,

```
$values = array('1',2);
```

– and with that the behavior is nothing but logical, because `$values[0]` is that text literal '1', and that has a first character that can be access using a zero based index.

So I guess either your *real* data is of a string type – or it maybe depends in the PHP version (I tested under 5.3.16).

Anyway, using `is_array` as the other answers already suggested is the right way to go here.

Comment: ahh yes! I was using a string as the first value of my array in my real code.