# How to check if multidimensional array contains multidimensional array pattern in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, validation, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for niftier check if multidim. array $a matches pattern (key/value) in multidim. array $b (or in other words, check if $b is a subarray of $a). My recursive traversal code with trace help attached below, ready to paste in an empty script.

This is needed to filter mdim array of products using mdim array of its chosen properties to match.

```
$a = array (
        "a" => "1",
        "b" => "red",
        "c" => array(
            "ca" => "ca123",            
            "cb" => "cb123",
        ),
        "d" => array(
            "da" => "da123",            
            "db" => "db123",
            "dc" => array(
                "dca" => "dca123",          
                "dcb" => "dcb123"           
            ),
            
        ),
);

$b = array(
    "b" => "red",
    "c" => array(
        "ca" => "ca123",            
    ),
    "d" => array(
        "dc" => array(
            "dca" => "dca123",          
        ),
        
    ),
);

function is_subarray(&$needle = array(), &$haystack = array()) 
{
    if (!$needle || !$haystack || !is_array($needle) || !is_array($haystack)) return FALSE;

    echo __FUNCTION__ . " ENTRY ****************************************************************<br />";
    echo "Needle: " . print_r($needle, TRUE) . "<br />Haystack: " . print_r($haystack, TRUE) . "<br />";

    foreach ($needle as $needle_key => $needle_value) {
        echo "Analyzing needle pair: " . print_r(array($needle_key => $needle_value), TRUE) . "<br />";
        echo "and haystack: " . print_r($haystack, TRUE) . "<br />";// . print_r($needle_value, true) . "<br />";
        if (array_key_exists($needle_key, $haystack) && (gettype($needle_value) == gettype($haystack[$needle_key]))) {
            // Keys matches and values type matches
            echo "Keys matches and values type matches<br />";
            if (is_array($needle_value)) {
                // Values are arrays - going deeper
                echo "Values are arrays - going deeper<br />";
                if (!is_subarray($needle_value, $haystack[$needle_key])) return FALSE;
            } else if ($needle_value != $haystack[$needle_key]) {
                // Values don't match - this is the end 
                echo "Values don't match - this is the end<br />";
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                // Values do match
                echo "Values do match<br />";
                //$result = true;
            }
        } else {
            // No key found - this is the end
            echo "No key found - this is the end<br />";
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    echo __FUNCTION__ . "**************************************************************** EXIT<br />";

    return TRUE;
}

echo "<br />Match: " . ((is_subarray($b, $a)) ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145337/checking-if-array-is-multidimensional-or-not

Comment: Recursive traversing

Comment: Maybe... At the beginning I was asking for help, but now, when I helped myself, I should close I think... Thanks!