# FosRestBundle single array and optional associative array

Tags: php, api, symfony, symfony4, fosrestbundle

I have a question about `@FOSRest\RequestParam`.
How can i give an optional option to request a bulk change.

For example:

```
$postValue = [
  'record_id' => 1234,
  'content' => "test",
  'ttl' => 0,
  'prio' => 0,
];
```

**VS**

```
$postValue = [
  [
  'record_id' => 1234,
  'content' => "test",
  'ttl' => 0,
  'prio' => 0,
  ],
  [
  'record_id' => 1234,
  'content' => "test",
  'ttl' => 0,
  'prio' => 0,
  ]
];
```

**The RequestParam is set like this:**

```
 * @FOSRest\RequestParam(name="record_id", allowBlank=false, requirements={"rule" = "\d+", "error_message" = "record_id must be an integer"}, strict=true, nullable=false, description="Record id")
 * @FOSRest\RequestParam(name="content", allowBlank=true, default="", description="Content")
 * @FOSRest\RequestParam(name="ttl", allowBlank=true, requirements={"rule" = "\d+", "error_message" = "ttl must be an integer"}, default={}, description="Time to live")
 * @FOSRest\RequestParam(name="priority", allowBlank=true, requirements={"rule" = "\d+", "error_message" = "priority must be an integer"}, default={}, description="Priority")
```

I know that using a `map=true` can be used for the 2nd example.
But is there a way to check which of the two examples is used and fetch the parameters based on the type of array?

I can solve the issue with `Request $request` but that's my last solution.

Hope you guys know a solution :)

Comment: you can check coming array is single-dimensional or multi-dimensional. see this thread answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37146075/4248328

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's outside the @FOSRest\RequestParam. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same result provided by FOSRestBundle.