# Check if multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

A call to an API can return different array structure based on if one or several sub-items. How can I with php easily check if the Identity is one or more?

Example array One identity

```
(
    [GetIdentitiesResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Identity] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => 123456789
                    [IsDefault] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Example More identities

```
(
    [GetIdentitiesResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Identity] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 223344
                            [IsDefault] => 
                       )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 112233
                            [IsDefault] => 
                         )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: is_array or is_object..

Comment: `is_array($result['GetIdentitiesResult']['Identity'])`

Comment: you can `count()` idedntity

Comment: If possible, change the API to return as an indexed array. you only need to assert the count(Identity) then.

Comment: Thats a poorly designed response from the API, if its yours, make it return an array ALWAYS even if there is only one occurance

Comment: Not my API and yes agree isn't the best setup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if array is multidimensional or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145337/checking-if-array-is-multidimensional-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

When you get the JSON response from the API, firstly you should do decode the JSON into an array like:

```
json_decode($yourJsonAPIResponse,true);
```

By using this code, you will always get the array not the object array.
I have tried to check your object array is multidimensional or not. Please review my code:
Firstly, I converted your object array into JSON by using this code:

```
$newJson = json_encode($yourJsonAPIResponse);
```

After this, I decoded the newJson into an array by using my code:

```
$array = json_decode($newJson,true);
```

After I created a function to check an array is multidimensional or not. I ref. this page and check 2nd example [Click here for info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-an-array-is-multidimensional-or-not-in-php/). I am pasting the function code here:

```
function is_multi($array) {
  $rv = array_filter($array, 'is_array');
  if(count($rv)>0) return true;
  return false;
}
// Output
var_dump(is_multi($e)); // return true
```

I hope this code will help you.
Thanks